# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') - React Router Issue

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, react-router

PropertyDetails.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../styles/propertydetails.css';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

function PropertyDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [propertyData, setPropertyData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch property details for the given propertyId using Axios
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/core/detail/${id}/`)
      .then((response) => {
        setPropertyData(response.data.results); 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching property details:', error);
      });
  }, [id]);

  if (!propertyData) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="property-details-container">
        <img src={propertyData.main_photo} alt={propertyData.title} className="main-photo" />
        <h2>{propertyData.title}</h2>
        <p>{propertyData.description}</p>
        <p>Price: ${propertyData.price}</p>
        <p>Bedrooms: {propertyData.bedrooms}</p>
        
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PropertyDetails;
```

App.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import HomePage from "../src/pages/HomePage"
import SalesPage from "../src/pages/SalesPage"
import RentalsPage from "../src/pages/RentalsPage"
import PropertyDetails from "../src/components/PropertyDetails"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <HomePage/> } />
              <Route path="sales" element={<SalesPage />} />
              <Route path="rentals" element={<RentalsPage />} />
              <Route path="/property/:id" element={<PropertyDetails />} />
          </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I've verified that the id parameter is correctly extracted using useParams. However, I'm still encountering this error. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it? Thank you!

I am fetching data from a django-rest api

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't appear to be the relevant code attempting to read some `params` property from an undefined reference. Please [edit] the post to include the complete error message and accompanying error stacktrace (*which should tell you right where the error was found*), and the correct relevant code for your [mcve]. If the error trace doesn't help you then try a global search in your code for any `params` reference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I changed this:

```
setPropertyData(response.data.results)
```

To:

```
setPropertyData(response.data)
```

---

So this was the final working code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch property details for the given propertyId using Axios
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/core/detail/${id}/`)
      .then((response) => {
        setPropertyData(response.data); 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching property details:', error);
      });
  }, [id]);
```

Answer (score -1):

<Route path="/property/:id" element={} />
In this, you are not sending anything in id, and you are expecting useParams to get some value of id from params.

As per my knowladge "/property/:id" is not used in React.
If you want to send something to params, use useNavigate of react-router.

From parent :   navigate('/createPost', { state: { postId: postData?._id, title: postData?.title, content: postData?.content } })

From Child to get the value :
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const { state } = useLocation()

Comment: `path="/property/:id"` is a perfectly valid path string used in `react-router`. This isn't the issue.